# Merge statement is not working with OUTPUT clause

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures

I am reading a data from CSV file and putting a data in data table. this dt i am sending to   stored procedure to insert/update . The below is my stored procedure :

*======================================

```
ALTER  PROC [dbo].[ups_InsertTVPOrderHeaders]
(
   @tvp [dbo].[TYPOrderHeaders] READONLY
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @InsertOutput TABLE
    (
      MergeAction VARCHAR(20),
      OrderHeaderID int

    );
  BEGIN TRY

  MERGE INTO dbo.OrderHeaders AS T
    USING @tvp AS S
    ON T.OrderHeaderID = S.OrderHeaderID
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                  UPDATE SET T.CustomerID = S.CustomerID,
                                 T.FirstName = S.FirstName,
                                 T.LastName = S.LastName

    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                     INSERT (OrderHeaderID,CustomerID,FirstName,LastName) 
                     VALUES (S.OrderHeaderID,S.CustomerID,S.FirstName,S.LastName)
        OUTPUT $action, inserted.OrderHeaderID INTO @InsertOutput;
        --OUTPUT $action, inserted.OrderHeaderID, Deleted.OrderHeaderID;
        --OUTPUT $action, DELETED.*, INSERTED.*;

      COMMIT TRANSACTION

SELECT * FROM @InsertOutput;        

  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH

  END CATCH
```

*===================================================================

C# Code calling SP part

```
  using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conStr))
            {
                con.Open();
                using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", SqlDbType.Structured);
                    param.Value = dt;
                    int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    return result;
                }
            }
```

==================================================================================
i am getting result as 0 . If i take out the ouput clause from sp. its works fine. Please can any one tell me what's wrong in output into statement. I wanted the insert/updated list of orderheaderID. Hence, i tried using output clause.

Answer (score 3):

You are using `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` which will not return results, only the number of rows affected. [According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx) this is what ExecuteNonQuery does:

> Executes a Transact-SQL statement against the connection and returns the number of rows affected.

You probably want to use [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx):

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(_conStr))
{
    con.Open();
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(procedureName, con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter param = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvp", SqlDbType.Structured);
        param.Value = dt;
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            int result = 0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // Do something with the reader, then increment result by 1 to get total rows affected
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: And, for what it's worth, outputting into the table valued parameter only to select it is redundant.

Comment: I have problem in stored procedure. it neither inserting nor updating. After it inserts/Update I wanted list of orderheaderid's. In my procedure OUTPUT clause is not working. could you please help me in SP

Comment: You have `COMMIT TRANSACTION` but no corresponding `BEGIN TRANSACTION`. This is probably the cause of your error. I would advise to remove `BEGIN TRY/END TRY, BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH` unless you are actually going to do something within the catch block. Otherwise just let the error be thrown, generally exception handling like this only serves to sweep problems under the carpet, rather than handling them properly!

Comment: Thanks for your help. I removed all BEGIN TRY/END TRY, BEGIN CATCH/END CATCH and able to debug. Yes it worked.. :)

Comment: I have one more query where from the SP i could get the status of '$action' as insert/update/delete. if any of the record get fail to insert/update/delete can i get that particular record as failed in output clause. if not please let me know how can i handle it.

Comment: This would not happen, `MERGE` is a single transaction, if one fails then they all fail and you will get nothing in the output.

Comment: This pointed my merge statement's to the right direction. The output was not printing nor showing 'update' when they should be 'inserted' while a transaction is happening.